# Npgsql Port 2.x to 3.x / 'NpgsqlTypes.BitString'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, npgsql

I updated my npgsql from 2.x for 3.x because according to the release notes, they fixed an issue that we have while querying JSONB column with +200k rows (queries with +2  "OR" clauses in where statement ).

The real problem is, when I try to use linq2db to access my login table, I get the follow exception. **"Could not load type 'NpgsqlTypes.BitString' from assembly 'Npgsql, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.**"

I tried updating the linq2db and then I got a diferent error: **"KeyWord Excpetion".**

Follows the used query

```
 var user =  (from  u in db.Usuario
                where u.Email == model.UserName
                  &&  u.Senha == model.Password
               select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

How you all went trough this problem ? How can I workaround this ?

I hope that i've been clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned in the migration notes to 3.0, Npgsql's BitString type was removed in 3.0 and replaced with the standard .NET type BitArray. You will need to change your code.

Comment: Sorry about this, but since I`m new in the development world, could you give me a hint ? Any doc would be apreciated

Comment: I have no idea what your code looks like. Start by recompiling, and you'll get compilation errors because there's no BitString. You'll need to replace places where BitString is used by .NET BitArray, here are the MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Shay Rojansky, I would like to thank you. After alot of research, I got the answer and it is pretty simple. I figured that I had none of BitString directly on my code but my old linq2db. Then I updated the version of Linq and removed the KeyWord "Protocol" from my connection string. This parameter was deprecated ? You know the revelance of it ? Apreciated your patience Sir.

Comment: Please read the migration notes carefully: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/migration.html. The Protocol parameter was removed since Npgsql only supports PostgreSQL protocol 3.